# NameError: unitialized constant ServiceName with default rspec configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I created `rails new --api whatever` with:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
```

in my `Gemfile`. Then, I created:

```
app/services/whatever_module/whatever_class.rb
```

and corresponding spec file:

```
spec/services/whatever_module/whatever_class_spec.rb
```

Now, when I run:

```
rspec services
```

I get this error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant WhateverModule

How do I tell rspec to recognize the module by its spec path?

Comment: are `whatever_class_spec.rb` and `calculate.rb` empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Your spec file should be in</s>

`spec/services/distamce/whatever_class_spec.rb`.

In you case rspec tries to find the WhateverModule because of `/whatever_module/` in your pathing for the spec file. You can try this to change to `spec/services/foo_bar/whatever_class_spec.rb` and you will get the missing FooBarModule error.

I think I figured out what you missed.

Rspec does not automatically require your app folder and so there are no modules or classes available from the app folder initially.

When you check https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#installation @2 then you can see you have to add some boilerplate files for rspec like `rails_helper.rb` and `spec_helper.rb` with `rails generate rspec:install`. These are responsible for all rspec related settings and the require of the app folder.

Also its required to add `require 'rails_helper'` on top of each spec file.

After you have done all this and you get the error `Unable to autoload constant WhateverModule::WhateverClass` then your `whatever_class.rb` has to look like this

```
module WhateverModule
  class WhateverClass
  end
end
```

Or you define the module in a file besides the `whatever_module` folder.

Comment: Hi there. It is my bad that I passed the wrong path in my question, it was set up as you write here and it still did not work. I am going to edit my question now, with the path you gave here. Here's an upvote for you, for trying. 

What I did (and it worked, but I don't like it) was adding `include WhateverModule::WhateverClass` on top of the `whatever_class_spec.rb` file. Rubocop went nuts about it and I don't think it is the correct solution.